# Overall Code Coverage including unrelated classes as well

Tags: unit-test, code-coverage

I have a sandbox org where I've created a trigger that calls another class containing a future method for final HTTP request. I have also created a test class and MockHttpRequest for it which is able to pass both the classes well above 90%. Now, the overall code coverage is still showing only 39% as it is also showing the result for two explicit classes(that I've not created in this test Org). The two classes are namely:

1. superSort
2. TrialCustomerPortalHomePageController

So my question is, do I need to cover test cases for these two classes as well before actual deployment, or should I just ignore these additional classes as I have no knowledge of them?

Answer (score 1):

You can deploy in Prod and choose [run-specified classes](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.daas.meta/daas/forcemigrationtool_deploy_run_specific_tests.htm) and just chose your classes that cover those classes

From Docs:

> If the code coverage of an Apex component in the deployment is less
>   than 75%, the deployment fails.

Well, this might look like a quick win, but in long run it come to haunt you. Delay the deployment until the whole org has 75%+ coverage.(Ideally, aim for 100%).

Also, it should not be brittle test classes to just cover code, but assert behaviour so that no unwanted side effects bugs pop up.

Comment: If its production, even if you choose test classes, the 2 extra classes should be covered right? Then how can you deploy without test classes for them?

Comment: @salesforce-sas The question mentioned about `ignore these additional classes` . I got inference that if OP is asking about if he can deploy just his/her classes in production

Answer (score 0):

For deployment, overall code coverage should be 75%. Whether it is your code or developed by others.

For deploying you have to create test classes for these classes. If that is not developed by you and developer is still in your team,you can ask him/her to create test classes. If developer is not part of your team, then you should create test classes based on mentioned class functionalities.