# Why are there default Apex classes in a newly created scratch org? superSort.cls and TrialCustomerPortalHomePageController.cls

Tags: apex, unit-test, scratch-org, cicd

I have a CI/CD pipeline and it creates a new scratch org for unit tests in the first stage.

I pushed all codes of an unlocked package into the scratch org and run the unit tests. However, two other Apex classes appeared in the scratch org:

1. superSort.cls
2. TrialCustomerPortalHomePageController.cls

I checked Apex Class page in setting and saw that they are last modified by "Pooled Org Admin". And they are not in my unlocked package.

As they are new, they are not covered by my test classes in the package.

So my question is:

1. Why do I have these two classes in the newly created scratch org? What are they for?
2. If they can not be avoided, how can I cover them in my test class?

Comment: Do you have communities enabled? Either in scratch org or in prod? if yes these are some communities related classes.Not sure on supersort class

Comment: Yes both in prod and in the scratch org communities are enabled.

Comment: So, Trial one is created by automatically bcz of community. I guess other one is because of some packages. I have not seen supersort class anywhere.

Comment: I have seen it here. https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/273877/overall-code-coverage-including-unrelated-classes-as-well but I couldn't find the answer to my question.

Comment: So I thought it might be something related by default.

Comment: Typically some of the community classes are coming with test classes. if those are not reqd you can delete it.

Comment: Since you mentioned unlocked package, it should not impact your CICD pipeline, since you'll be running the test classes on package related classes.

Comment: The thing is I did not create it, and it appeared in the scratch org by itself. Do you mean that I should add a command in .gitlab-ci.yml to delete these two classes?

Comment: No, if its not present in the force-app/default/main/classes, test run will not include (on local test classes)